# Searchkick and PostgreSQL with money field type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to enable a search using seachkick, but in my PostgreSQL I have a couple of fields whose type is `money`. Unfortunately searchkick does not search on those fields; is there anything I need to do in order to fix that?

For example there's a row containing `$1,000.00` but no matter if I search for exactly that, or 1000 or anything similar; it is just never found.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

introduce those values to elasticsearch as strings

```
class Item
  include searchkick word_middle: %i[name price]

 def search_data
  {
    name: self.name
    price: self.price.to_s
   }
 end

end
```